# How magnetic monopole modifies faraday's law

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles

I have encountered a statement that upon existence of magnetic monopoles, the equation
$$\nabla \times \textbf{E} = -\partial_t \textbf{B}$$
must be modified.

I only see that the last equation
$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{B} =0$$
should be modified, but not the first equation. Can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: Hint: The magnetic charges must satisfy a continuity equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equation needs a term to account for the magnetic current density, since the introduction of monopoles admits the possibility that they can move - producing a current.